# How to assign md5 of another file to one wav file?

Tags: hash, md5, preimage-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

Good afternoon . Please tell me how to change the md5 hash of one wav file to the md5 hash of another wav file. I want to bypass the anti-cheat check on md5. Maybe there are online paid services? I know English badly. I know that there have already been similar topics, but I could not do anything. Thanks!

Comment: That would be a second preimage attack or a first preimage attack on MD5 (depending on if you know the other wav file, or only it's hash). We don't know how to perform this at feasible cost. The best we know is preparing two distinct files (wav or not) with the same MD5 hash.

Comment: the second wav file is available

Comment: That's the definition of a preimage attack. Preimage means you've got a specific message (in this case file content) to match. What you could do is to try and alter the file in such a way that you still have the original sound *and* the same hash. Good luck.